# PowerShell - Filter childitem based off filename and extension

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to filter a result based off the filename with a variable for the previous day and the file extension.

I have attempted to filter using different methods but the latest is the closes I have gotten.

```
$Date = Get-Date #-Format "yyyyMMdd"
$DateAdd = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$DateStr = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $DateAdd

$srcRoot = "U:\test\Processed"  
$exRoot = "U:\test\Extract" 


Get-ChildItem $srcRoot -Filter *.zip | Where-object -Property Name -Like *$DatStr  | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath $exRoot -Force
```

As of right now the code gets all the compressed files in the srcRoot directory. I am only trying to return the compressed file for the date variable.

Comment: I see a type here, in `Where-object` you are looking for ` *$DatStr `, this should probably be `$DateStr`

Comment: Why not use `-Filter "<asterisk>$DateStr<asterisk>.zip"`?

Comment: Is the date is part of the filename, or do you want to use the actual file date?

Comment: @FoxDeploy, When I attempt just the $DateStr the entire script appears to ignore the ```Get-ChildItem $srcRoot -Filter *.zip | Where-Object -Property Name -Like $DateStr ``` and goes straight to the Expand-Archive statement.

Comment: @AdminOfThings , thank you for the recommendation. That works as needed, I probably had the syntax incorrect from one of my earlier tests.

Answer (score 1):

Using recommendation from AdminOfThings 's comment above. I was able to filter the results as I was attempting.

```
Get-ChildItem $srcRoot -Filter "*$DateStr*.zip"
```

This returns the correct file after testing.